# redirect to root URL when refreshing with locationType=hash in Ember

Tags: apache, nginx, ember.js, ember-cli

Hi I set my locationType in config/environment.js to hash.

Now it won't produce a 404 when I refresh on a non-index route. However, when I refresh, it always directs me to root URL.

Is that the intended design? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should this always be handled by the web server or inside Ember?

Comment: The webserver can't handle this (because you use the hash). So what *should* ember do? You can implement a 404 page in ember with a wildcard route.

Comment: @Lux Thanks for replying. I can fix the 404 error using hash locationType. If I don't use hash, is there a way to solve the 404 problem in web server? If not, is there a way to not refresh to root URL all the time in Ember?

Comment: You webserver will never know which route is valid and which not. If you use the hash locationType it won't also know which route you visit. The correct way to provide a good 404 page is a [wildcard route](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_wildcard-globbing-routes).